# Create x number of rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to generate a synthetic population of a city from a sample. I have all the attributes of the sample population in a spreadsheet with the weight of each person.
To generate the population I need to repeat each row (one person's information) by the number of times given by its weight. I'm trying to read the spreadsheet as a matrix in matlab and then use repmat to duplicate rows for each person in the sample as per its weight.
I'm not very sure about the matlab syntax.

Comment: Can you share your attempt so far?

Comment: Also, can you provide more details about how your data is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your weights in an array `w`, and your data in a matrix `datamatrix`
you can do something like this:

```
%read in your data
% w = weights of the rows
cc = [0 cumsum(w)];
idx = zeros(1,sum(w));

for i=1:length(w)
   idx(cc(i)+1:cc(i+1))=i;
end
weighted_replicated_matrix = datamatrix(idx,:);
```

What this does is to generate the indexes for each row as many times as the weight value. Then it just selects the given indexes from the original datamatrix (resulting in replication of rows)

Comment: it's a simple run-length coding - no need for loop. `cumsum` can do the work.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a vector `count` that says for each entry how many time to repeat it
(`count` must contain non-negative integers).
So, for example, if `count = [2 0 3 1]` you'll create 2 copies of the first entry, none of the second, three copies of the third entry and 1 copy from the fourth.

How to do so, given `count`:

```
>> ind = zeros( sum( count ) );
>> ind( cumsum([ 0 count(1:end-1) ] ) ) = 1:numel(count);
>> ind = cumsum(ind);
>> population = example( ind, : ); % create population matrix with count rows of each line in example.
```